# Pygame snake game attribute error when trying to draw characters

Tags: python, pygame, attributeerror

Line 134 I get an attribute error and I'm fairly new to pygame so I believe it has something to do with my arguments but I'm not sure. This is the line the error is on:

```
pygame.draw.rect(window.pygame.Color("RED"), pygame.Rect(int(foodpos[0]), int(foodpos[1]), 10, 10))
```

The exact error is:

```
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'pygame'.
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\backend.py", line 1744, in _trace
    return self._trace_and_catch(frame, event, arg)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\backend.py", line 1819, in _trace_and_catch
    assert last_custom_frame.event.startswith("before_")
AssertionError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\CS 20 School Projects\Daily Work.py", line 134, in <module>
    pygame.draw.rect(window.pygame.Color("RED"), pygame.Rect(int(foodpos[0]), int(foodpos[1]), 10, 10))
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'pygame'"""
```

```
import pygame, sys, random, time

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (225, 225, 225)
BLUE = (0, 0, 225)
RED = (225, 0, 0)


class Snake(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.position = [100, 50]  # sets initial position of the snake
        self.body = [[100, 50], [90, 50], [80, 50]]  # sets initial length of the snakes body to 3 segments
        self.direction = "RIGHT"
        self.change_direction_to = self.direction

    # ---------------------------- Makes it possible to change directions but you cannot go directly backwards
    def change_direction_to(self, dir):
        if dir == "RIGHT" and not self.direction == "LEFT":
            self.direction = "RIGHT"
        elif dir == "LEFT" and not self.direction == "RIGHT":
            self.direction = "LEFT"
        elif dir == "UP" and not self.direction == "DOWN":
            self.direction = "UP"
        elif dir == "DOWN" and not self.direction == "UP":
            self.direction = "DOWN"

    # ----------------------------

    # -------------------------------- Sets the speed of the snake
    def move(self):
        if self.direction == "RIGHT":
            self.position[0] += 10
        if self.direction == "LEFT":
            self.position[0] -= 10
        if self.direction == "UP":
            self.position[0] += 10
        if self.direction == "DOWN":
            self.position[0] -= 10
        # ---------------------------------

        # ----------------------------- Checks if snake has ate food
        self.body.insert(0, list(self.position))
        if self.position == foodpos:
            return 1
        else:
            self.body.pop()
            return 0

    # -----------------------------

    # ---------------------------------checks if snake has hit a wall
    def check_collision(self):
        if self.position[0] > 490 or self.position < 0:
            return 1
        elif self.position[1] > 490 or self.position < 0:
            return 1
        # ----------------------------------

        # ---------------------------checks if snake has hit itself
        for body_part in self.body[1:]:
            if self.position == body_part:
                return 1
        return 0

    # ---------------------------

    def get_head_position(self):
        return self.position

    def get_body(self):
        return self.body


class FoodSpawner:

    def __init__(self):
        self.position = [random.randrange(1, 50) * 10], [random.randrange(1, 50) * 10]
        self.is_food_on_screen = True

    def spawn_food(self):
        if not self.is_food_on_screen:
            self.position = [random.randrange(1, 50) * 10], [random.randrange(1, 50) * 10]
            self.is_food_on_screen = True
        return self.position

    def set_food_on_screen(self, b):
        self.is_food_on_sceen = b


window = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Definitely Not Snake")
fps = pygame.time.Clock()

score = 0

snake = Snake()
food_spawner = FoodSpawner()


def game_over():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        # ------------------------- quits the game
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_over()
        # -------------------------

        # ------------------------- movement of the snake
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                snake.change_dir_to("RIGHT")
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                snake.change_dir_to("LEFT")
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                snake.change_dir_to("UP")
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                snake.change_dir_to("DOWN")
    # -------------------------

    # ----------------------------- adds to score if the snake eats the food
    foodpos = food_spawner.spawn_food()
    if snake.move(foodpos) == 1:
        score += 1
        food_spawner.set_food_on_screen(False)
    # ------------------------------

    # ------------------------------ draws the screen, the snake, and its food
    window.fill(pygame.Color("BLACK"))
    for pos in snake.get_body():
        pygame.draw.rect(window, pygame.Color("BLUE"), pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 10, 10))
    pygame.draw.rect(window.pygame.Color("RED"), pygame.Rect(int(foodpos[0]), int(foodpos[1]), 10, 10))
    # ------------------------------

    if snake.check_collision() == 1:
        game_over()
    pygme.display.set_caption("Definitely not Snake | Score : " + str(score))
    pygame.display.flip()
    fps.tick(24)
```

Comment: you need `comma` instead of `dot` after `window` in `pygame.draw.rect(window, pygame.Color("RED")`. (instead of `pygame.draw.rect(window.pygame.Color("RED")`)

Comment: `self.position = [random.randrange(1, 50) * 10], [random.randrange(1, 50) * 10]` has to be `self.position = [random.randrange(1, 50) * 10, random.randrange(1, 50) * 10]` The first on is a tuple where each element is a list `([x], [y])` the 2nd one is a list with 2 elements `[x, y]`

Answer (score 1):

```
    for pos in snake.get_body():
        pygame.draw.rect(window,pygame.Color("BLUE"),pygame.Rect(pos[0],pos[1],10,10))
                               ^
    pygame.draw.rect(window.pygame.Color("RED"), pygame.Rect(int(foodpos[0]), int(foodpos[1]), 10, 10))
                           ^
```

I believe there is a typo. Since there is no error in your blue drawing, it should by the 'window.pygame' error.

Comment: That is correct - whoops. but when I fix that I just get an error on that line:       AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'pygame'
Daily Work.py, line 133

Comment: The same error again? Check where `pygame` appears in your code and make sure no more typos before those locations.

Comment: Same error (no spelling errors that I can see.).. this is what it says and the suggestions to look for..       
 .AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'pygame'
Daily Work.py, line 133
Your program tries to access attribute pygame of an object of type 'pygame.Surface', but this type doesn't have such attribute.
Did you misspell the name?
Don't forget that case of the letters matters too!
Did you expect another type?

Comment: Is it in the line where you draw blue rects? Did you unexpectedly change the correct line?

Comment: """Think fixed previous problem - 
I believe something is wrong with my rectangle argument - the part of the code i get the error on is shown below:(its line 134 in full code above)
TypeError: Argument must be rect style object
Daily Work.py, line 134
Python was asked to do an operation with an object which doesn't support it.
"""

    window.fill(pygame.Color("BLACK"))
    for pos in snake.get_body():
        pygame.draw.rect(window,pygame.Color(0,225,0),pygame.Rect(pos[0],pos[1],10,10))
    pygame.draw.rect(window,pygame.Color(225,0,0),pygame.Rect(foodpos[0],foodpos[1],10,10))

Answer (score 0):

In the method `spawn_food`

> ```py
> self.position = [random.randrange(1, 50) * 10], [random.randrange(1, 50) * 10]
> ```

has to be

```py
self.position = [random.randrange(1, 50) * 10, random.randrange(1, 50) * 10]
```

The first on is a tuple where each element is a list `([x], [y])` the 2nd one is a list with 2 elements `[x, y]`

Note, `spawn_food` returns `self.position` an the return value is assigned to `foodpos`:

> ```py
> foodpos = food_spawner.spawn_food()
> ```

Since `foodpos` is a tuple containing lists with 1 element (`([x], [y])`), that causes an error in

> ```py
> pygame.Rect(int(foodpos[0]), int(foodpos[1]), 10, 10)
> ```